# MySQL create temporary table without database selected

Tags: mysql, temp-tables

I'm trying to create a temporary table to run some tests.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=MEMORY DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

It tells me that there is no database selected. I don't want to create a database for this purpose and I couldn't find anything about temporary databases. And no I don't want to create a database and then drop it, I'd like this script to run even if the user doesn't have create database permissions.

How can I create a temporary table, run a few queries then drop it, as the connection closes?

Comment: A table can only exist as part of a DB

Comment: why don't you want to create a db ?

Comment: If you don't want DBs consider other technologies.

Comment: @P.Salmon why would I not want DBs?

Comment: @GuyLouzon as I said, because it would require the user to have create database privileges

Comment: @php_nub_qq - ' I don't want to create a database for this purpose' -

Comment: @P.Salmon that is taken out of context.

Comment: ok then, why not have a database preset, to which the php mysqli will connect to. an empty one, where the php user will only have access to create temp tables (which are session related of course)

Comment: @GuyLouzon because I'm creating a client library that will run in an unknown environment. I wanted to avoid forcing users of the library to have a create-database-enabled mysql user account but I guess I'll just add it as a requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply, you can't.

As Long as you don't use

```
USE testdb;
```

Or enter a database in your connecting string.

The program can't add anything and creating a temp table

The database is  a reference point for the mysql program and is absolutely needed,even for temporary tables and everything else

Comment: So would it be okay to use information_schema? AFAIK that's pretty much guaranteed to exist on just about any system.

Comment: @php_nub_qq - corrupt Information_schema =  corrupt all DBs You should avoid.

Comment: you usually don't have access to that tables, so that isn't really an option, if you can add tables to information_schema you can do it also on the tabke you access to get information. The only problem as far as i can see, is that you don't have privileges to add a table and that would include information_schema

Answer (score 1):

You can use an already existing database to create the temporary table

mysql> SHOW databases;
mysql> use databasename
The name that is available.

But temporary table cannot be created without connecting to a DB.

The temp table only exists for that specific session. After the connection is established to a specific DB we can create and query the temp table.